Add data to existing rows of BufDataGridView
I have a BufDataGridView called Data, and the data class of items is called Test.  Data has 4 columns: Serial No, Location, Test1, and Test2. I have a function set up to import 40 rows of serial numbers into Data.   Data is linked to binding list SerialNo which has test object serialNo.  I want my code to systematically input data into each row after taking new data.  After 20 rows, i have a dialog setup as a break to change test setup, and then it continues taking the next 20.  I have this done through a for loop that iterates through said 20 times.  the problem im having is that, once i import the data and press the test button, it will only put data into the top row, and then not an of the others.  Am i asking it to print data to each row properly?
EDIT: the data rows are already imported, im looking for how to add data into each row of the grid.
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {

        Test newTest = new();

        newTest.test1 = 0;
        newTest.test2 = 0;
        
        // moves cursor to next row
        staveEATData2.CurrentCell = staveEATData2.Rows[^2].Cells[0];
    }

    var question = new TestForm();
    question.ShowDialog();


    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {

        Test newTest = new();

        newTest.test1 = 0;
        newTest.test2 = 0;
        
        // moves cursor to next row
        staveEATData2.CurrentCell = staveEATData2.Rows[^2].Cells[0];
    }

}```



This code is doing absolutely nothing, neither setting anything nor importing anything -- Data has 4 rows: you mean 4 Columns

@Jimi the load data button is in a different section of code, and yes i did mean columns. What is needed to add the data from the class into the datagridview?

Set the DataSource of the DataGridView to the collection you have (a BindingList?), provided that the Column, that it appears you have added in the Designer, are linked to the Properties of the objects in this collection (i.e., you have set the DataPropertyName of the Columns). Or, you could just set the DataSource, let the Control generate the Columns for you, then change the text of the Headers, if needed -- Your scenario is not clear at all, these are just suppositions. Be more precise when you describe what you have there

I've read it twice still not able to figure out what exactly you are trying to achieve and have done in your code.
